# Is there a comprehensive list of options for \cite[]{} and analogous commands?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, citing

I'm looking for some reference manual online listing the available options for the command:

`\cite[<option(s)>]{<reference(s)>}`

and other commands within the same family such as `\parencite[]{}`.

Is there one I can find? Otherwise, can someone give coverage on how to make proper use of the options for `\cite`.

I'm particularly interested in citing the title of a section within a book along with the pages. I'm using biblatex with bibtex as the back-end in MLA style.

Comment: Have you looked in the manual for `biblatex`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes. Maybe you can reference the specific section, if there is anything to find there. I search for the term `cite` within the manual opened in Adobe Acrobat. Found nothing. Maybe I missed it.

Comment: The term "cite" must have come up quite a lot, but look in the table of contents instead: In  chapter 3 *User Guide* there is a section 3.8 *Citation commands*.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It gives a comprehensive list of templates for the different citation commands but not how to properly implement those "pre" and "post" arguments nor what the available arguments are.

Comment: There are no arguments, just the text that you want printed.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Ok. So I can type `\cite[section title, page 2 through 3]{referenceinbibfile}` as well as `\cite[section title, p. 2-3]{referenceinbibfile}` and their both equally valid in terms of biblatex?

Comment: Meaning I would have to format the arguments themselves manually according to the particular style manual I'm following (e.g. APA, CMS)?

Comment: Yes, both work just fine. I don't think there is any special parsing of pre/postnotes, so do formatting as you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The manual would be logical place to look, in that for the current version (3.7) of `biblatex` citation commands is described in section 3.8 *Citation commands*.

As you can see there, all single cite commands are basically the same:

```
\cite[prenote][postnote]{citationkey}
```

the `prenote` is printed before the citation, `postnote` after. If you provide just one of them, that becomes a postnote. If you want just a prenote, add an empty postnote.

As mentioned by moewe in a comment, note also that if the postnote contains only a number/number range, many styles will format it as e.g. "p. 42" or "pp. 42-43", not just "42" or "42--43".

Quick example to demonstrate:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\verb|\cite[foo][bar]{aksin}| & \cite[foo][bar]{aksin} \\
\verb|\cite[foo]{aksin}|      & \cite[foo]{aksin} \\
\verb|\cite[foo][]{aksin}|    & \cite[foo][]{aksin} \\
\verb|\cite[foo][42]{aksin}|  & \cite[foo][42]{aksin}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So in my particular case I have to type: `\cite[``sectiontitlewithinbook''][pages]{bookreferencedinbibfile}`? Yes?

Comment: @RichardSantiago Hard to answer when I don't know what output you want ... But if you want `<section title> <citation>, <pages>`, then yes.

Comment: The only thing to mention is that many styles format the postnote as a page reference if it is a range of numbers. So it is often unnecessary to write `\cite[p.~12]{sigfridsson}`, `\cite[12]{sigfridsson}` is enough.

Comment: @moewe Thank you, I'll add a note about that in the answer.